# PMDC Motor Characteristic Graph

Tags: motors, torque, power, energy-efficiency

I am trying create a graph similar to as shown below. However, I am confused as to how the torque is related to the characteristics.

The graph that is to be replicated for certain parameters:
[image]

The parameters that I have been given are:

[image]

All parameter values are known, however, no function of the torque is known. However, I have been given the following 2 equations:

[image]

So my question is how is torque related to the efficiency, power, current and speed, as I have conducted research on how these graphs are plotted but didn't find anything that helped. As I only know of single points and not full functions of the dependency of the paramteres on the torque. I am using MATLAB to plot these, below is the most up to date script:

```
v = 24; %voltage = 24 V
r = 0.7; %resistance = 0.7 ohms
j = 7.95e-5; %inertia of the rotor = 7.95e-5 kgm^2
k = 0.059; %motor constant = 0.059 Vs/rad
b = 6.65e-5; %damping coefficient = Nms/rad
l = 9.8e-4; %inductance = 9.8e-4 H
i = 0.4494; %steady state current = 0.4494 A
w = 400; %steady state angular velocity = 400 rad/s
T_l = 0; %Torque applied to the motor = 0; 
time_period = 0.0014; %time period of the circuit = 0.0014 s

torque = 0:0.1:2;

I = ((v-k*w)/r)*torque + i;
figure
plot(torque,I);
xlabel('Torque');
ylabel('Current');
```

The equation I used for `I` is something I made up and I am not sure how correct this is; I thought of trying this because the example graph shows a linear relationship between current and torque. The graph that I got was:
[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

P.S. I know it's a long read, but thanks for reading the entire thing.